# ESRI State Plane Coordinates as EPSG

Tags: qgis, gdal, coordinate-system, epsg

I am working with some State Plane projections from Colorado.  I have looked them up on spatialreference.org and they are the following:

```
ESRI:102254: NAD 1983 HARN StatePlane Colorado Central FIPS 0502
ESRI:102654: NAD 1983 StatePlane Colorado Central FIPS 0502 Feet
```

I am wondering how I reference this coordinate in QGIS or FWTools using an EPSG code.  When I load this data it comes up as a User 10000 value.

Any help would be great.
Thanks...

Comment: I had a similar problem:

http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43378/is-there-a-difference-between-esris-nad83-indiana-spw-and-qgiss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the [prj to epsg](http://prj2epsg.org)  online service quite useful in the past for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 4):

Latest builds of QGIS Master and GDAL have these EPSG codes. You can install them with OSGEO4W (package qgis-dev) in parallel to your working QGIS installation, or GDAL dev binaries from gisinternals.

You can then reproject the data to a CRS that your working copy of QGIS knows.